# $.ajax isnot working while calling a PlayController

Tags: playframework-2.0

Unable to understand why this `ajax` post doesnot work while calling my Play controller

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '/login',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: "{username:"+user+",password:"+pass+"}",
        success : responseLogin,
        error : errorLogin
     });
```

My route.conf

```
 POST    /login                           controllers.UserController.authenticate()
```

Controller code :

```
   DynamicForm data = form().bindFromRequest();
   User user =     User.authenticate( data.get("username"),data.get("password"));
```

But this code works :

```
  $.post('/login',
                    {'username':$("#txtUsername").val(),'password':$("#txtPassword").val()},
                    function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                    });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change your `$.ajax` call to send data like your `$.post` call does?  (`$.post` calls `$.ajax` under the hood.)

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '/login',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {'username':$("#txtUsername").val(),'password':$("#txtPassword").val()},
        success : responseLogin,
        error : errorLogin
     });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your `$.ajax` initial call, your string isn't properly formatted JSON, so that could be part of the problem.  Also, I don't know what `user` and `pass` look like (what values they hold), so that may also be part of the problem.  I'm glad that helped.